# This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first

Tags: web3js, react

I am in the final stages of developing an application that is similar to https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale, however, when I click on the create button, my Metamask modal is not popping up to ask me if I want to approve or reject the transaction.

This is my `pages/campaigns/requests/new.js` file where this is all taking place:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Message, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Campaign from "../../../ethereum/campaign";
import web3 from "../../../ethereum/web3";
import { Link, Router } from "../../../routes";
import Layout from "../../../components/Layout";

class RequestNew extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "",
    description: "",
    recipient: ""
  };

  static async getInitialProps(props) {
    const address = props.query;

    return { address };
  }

  onSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const campaign = Campaign(this.props.address);
    const { description, value, recipient } = this.state;

    try {
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      await campaign.methods
        .createRequest(description, web3.utils.toWei(value, "ether"), recipient)
        .send({ from: accounts[0] });
    } catch (err) {}
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h3>Create a Request</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Description</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.description}
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({ description: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Form.Field>
            <label>Value in Ether</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={event => this.setState({ value: event.target.value })}
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Form.Field>
            <label>Recipient</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.recipient}
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({ recipient: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Button primary>Create!</Button>
        </Form>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default RequestNew;
```

This is my `ethereum/campaign.js` file:

```
import web3 from './web3';
import Campaign from './build/Campaign.json';

export default address => {
  return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(Campaign.interface), address);
};
```

This is my `ethereum/web3.js` file:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

let web3;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // we are in the browser and metamask is running
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // we are on the server *OR* the user is not running metamask
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/abc123'
  );
  web3 = new Web3(provider);
}

export default web3;
```

Can anybody see where I missed a step? I am not getting any errors of any sort, just not getting the behavior thats expected when creating a transaction with the Create button which is for Metamask modal to pop up.

So I decided to add some error handling in my `try/catch` block:

```
onSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const campaign = Campaign(this.props.address);
    const { description, value, recipient } = this.state;

    this.setState({ loading: true, errorMessage: "" });

    try {
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      await campaign.methods
        .createRequest(description, web3.utils.toWei(value, "ether"), recipient)
        .send({ from: accounts[0] });

      Router.pushRoute(`/campaigns/${this.props.address}/requests`);
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message });
    }

    this.setState({ loading: false });
  };

render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h3>Create a Request</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} error={!!this.state.errorMessage}>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Description</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.description}
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({ description: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Form.Field>
            <label>Value in Ether</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={event => this.setState({ value: event.target.value })}
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Form.Field>
            <label>Recipient</label>
            <Input
              value={this.state.recipient}
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({ recipient: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </Form.Field>
```

And sure enough when I tried creating a request again I was able to see the following error message render to the screen:

**This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first**

I am not sure how I do not have an address set yet on this contract object.

Comment: In case somebody still stuck. Try login metamask on diff net and then back to target net. in my case I clicked on ganache nd then rospnet. And it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit in my code, instead of this:

```
static async getInitialProps(props) {
    const address = props.query;

    return { address };
  }
```

I need to have it like this:

```
static async getInitialProps(props) {
    const { address } = props.query;

    return { address };
  }
```

Comment: You're allowed to accept your own answer for the win. You can also edit the title and content so it might show up in a search when someone else has a similar issue. Thanks for posting this resolution to the question.

Answer (score 3):

"This contract object doesn't have address set yet" -- This error can also occur if the address you have assigned is incorrect; it doesn't exist, or you pasted in the txhash instead of the contract address.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when running a react truffle box, compiler 0.7.0.

After using

```
truffle develop
```

I forgot to actually migrate the contract. I'm only a few days into learning but I enjoyed the lesson.

Perhaps those who find themselves here will avoid this mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error. I figured out, the following code was written:

```
const campaign = Campaign(props.query.address);
```

But I forgot to add the `await` keyword, which is required as `web3` takes time in creating the `campaign object` for us. Following is the corrected code:

```
const campaign = await Campaign(props.query.address);
```